# Docker - Mantain folder and file in server when update

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new using docker and I want to mantain my media folder and sqlite file on the server when I update the container, but I don't know how to make it.

My dockerfile have:

```
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN mkdir media
RUN mkdir media/media
RUN mkdir media/projetos
RUN mkdir media/uploads

RUN chmod g+w /app
RUN chmod g+w /app/db.sqlite3
RUN chmod g+w media/
RUN chmod g+w media/media
RUN chmod g+w media/projetos
RUN chmod g+w media/uploads
```

And my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  arq_web:
    image: creativerender.azurecr.io/arq_web:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I don't know if I have to use the volume tag on my docker compose, I tried something like:

```
volumes:
- ./media:/app/media
```

But without success.

Answer (score 0):

When you use volumes in the docker-compose it will override everything that you copied at build time.

```
volumes:
  - ./media:/app/media
```

So anything that is copied in Dockerfile, the volume will override it.

```
ADD . /app
```

To want to keep just media and sqllite file from the host then you can try

```
volumes:
  - ./media:/app/media/media
  - ./db.sqlite3:/app/db.sqlite3
```

I think your media folder is `/app/media/media` as you creating in dockerfile.

```
RUN mkdir media/media
```

Comment: Thanks,,, But it returns: Cannot create container for service arq_web: b'Drive has not been shared'

Comment: Share the drive

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you upgrade to version 3 syntax of Docker Compose than I suggest you to use named volumes (https://success.docker.com/article/different-types-of-volumes) to handle volumes in your services because Docker will handle how the volume will be created.

This is the link to docker-compose file reference of using volumes (including named volumes) https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes